# Navigation bar not working on video background

Tags: html, css

I'm very new to HTML and CSS so please excuse if my coding is terrible.

I'm trying to add a navigation bar to the website and it has a video as the background, The website does display the navigation bar but it does not let me click on it.

I noticed when I remove the nav `class="navigation"` code, it turns it into a simple navigation bar but I am able to click on it. (I know it works cause there is a line under the text eg home, discover etc when I hover my mouse over it)

I have attached a photo of how I want the navigation bar to look like:

[image]

Someone please help me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Tourist Guide | Sweeties</title>

<header>
  <div class="header">
    <nav class="navigation">
      <a href="#" class="navbar-logo">Sweeties</a>
      <div class="navbar-right">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
        <a href="#">Discover</a>
        <a href="#">Reservations</a>
        <a href="#">About Us</a>
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
        <a href="#">About Developer</a>
        
      </div>
    </nav>
    
    <style>
    
        .navigation{
        padding-top:30px;
        padding-bottom:30px;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        width:100%;
        z-index:1;
    }

        .navbar-right{
        float:right;
        padding-right:10%;
    }

        .navbar-right a{
        text-decoration:none;
        padding:10px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-family:Calibri;
        font-weight:900;
        font-size: 25px;
    }

        .navbar-right a:hover{
        text-decoration:underline;
    }
        .navbar-logo{
        padding-left:10%;
        font-family:Calibri;
        font-size:30px;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#FFFFFF; 

    }

        .video-container {
        z-index: -100;
        width:100%;
        height:75%;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }

        #video-bg{
        width:100%;
 
        }

        .portfolio-section{
        margin-top:50%;
    }
        .tagline-left{
        float:left;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
    }

        .tagline-right{
        float:right;
        width:50%;
        text-align:center;
    }

        .tagline-video{
        width:75%;
    }

        .tagline-right-text{
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:9%;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left:17%;
        font-family:Calibri;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        width:290px;
        font-size:40px;
    }

        .tagline-left-text{
        position:absolute;
        margin-top:9%;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left:11%;
        font-family:Calibri;
        color:#fff;
        width:375px;
        font-size:40px;
    }

</style>


        
        <style type="text/css">
            
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body {
                font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
            }

            .background-wrap {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: -1000;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
            }
            
        
            #video-bg-elem {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
            }


            .content {
                position: absolute;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                z-index: 1000;
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            }
            .content h1 {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 100px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: 300;
                color: #fff;
                padding-top: 15%;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
            }
            .content p {
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 50px;
                letter-spacing: 3px;
                color: #aaa;
            }
            
                        
        </style>
        
    </head>
    <body>
            

        <div class="background-wrap">
            <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted"> 
                <source src="Videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>          
        </div>


        <div class="content">         
            <h1>Fiji Islands</h1>
            <p>Welcome to Fiji's #1 Tourist Guide Website</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: attached a photo : https://i.stack.imgur.com/cL6jF.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change z-index of `navigation` class

```
.navigation{
    z-index:1001;
}
```

Check the answer

Codepen : https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/qBZRaeo

```css
.navigation{
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:1001;
}

.navbar-right{
    float:right;
    padding-right:10%;
}

.navbar-right a{
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size: 25px;
}

.navbar-right a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #111;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.navbar-logo{
    padding-left:10%;
    font-family:Calibri;
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFFFFF; 

}

.video-container {
    z-index: -100;
    width:100%;
    height:75%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}

#video-bg{
    width:100%;

}

.portfolio-section{
    margin-top:50%;
}
.tagline-left{
    float:left;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
}

.tagline-right{
    float:right;
    width:50%;
    text-align:center;
}

.tagline-video{
    width:75%;
}

.tagline-right-text{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:9%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:17%;
    font-family:Calibri;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    width:290px;
    font-size:40px;
}

.tagline-left-text{
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:9%;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:11%;
    font-family:Calibri;
    color:#fff;
    width:375px;
    font-size:40px;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
}

.background-wrap {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: -1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}


#video-bg-elem {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}


.content {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
.content h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.content p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Tourist Guide | Sweeties</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header">
      <nav class="navigation">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-logo">Sweeties</a>
        <div class="navbar-right">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
          <a href="#">Discover</a>
          <a href="#">Reservations</a>
          <a href="#">About Us</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
          <a href="#">About Developer</a>

        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="background-wrap">
    <video id="video-bg-elem" autoplay loop="loop" muted="muted"> 
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    </video>          
  </div>

  <div class="content">         
    <h1>Fiji Islands</h1>
    <p>Welcome to Fiji's #1 Tourist Guide Website</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you check this demo https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/qBZRaeo @Deondaray

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes I made to HTML I reorder it. am not sure if that's acceptable by you. also in case, you don't want to change the order.
just give `.navigation` z-index higher than the `.content` and it should work. as well

```
.navigation{
    z-index:1001;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <header class="header">
        <nav class="navigation">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-logo">Sweeties</a>
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Discover</a>
                <a href="#">Reservations</a>
                <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                <a href="#">About Developer</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="background-wrap">
            <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop"> 
                <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Fiji Islands</h1>
                <p>Welcome to Fiji's #1 Tourist Guide Website</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-right a {
    color: #cccccc;
    /* changed color */
}

.navbar-logo {
    color: #cccccc;
    /* changed color */
}
```

that's how it looks for me

[image: results]